# Not able to verify callback on Gupshup WhatsApp APIs

Tags: node.js, whatsapp, gupshup

I am following this guide to build NodejS bot using Gupshup whatsapp https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/gupshup-bot-library-for-node

I am running the code and getting the ngrok URL:
[image]

But when following steps are given, I get an error as below:
[image]

Not sure what is wrong here. Please let me know how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ngrok service can be not reachable (for any reason).
First - make sure you can open ngrok link in the browser or by curl and make sure it reaches your server api.

Also if your backend check incoming requests for specific app key in header, you should also add it to url params, due to you have no way to manage GupShup api caller.

Answer (score 0):

for the first time setting callback you need to return a 200 status.

```
res.status(200).send('ok');
```

Use this as first line for first time for setting callback and after call back is set you can comment this out. And save and relauch your code (make sure address of your hosted code is same don't restart ngrok :P) is same